# Find template type of a template type c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-traits

I would like to have a function that can take many different things (for simplicity) like so:

```
template <typename T>
typename type_to_return<T>::type   // <-- Use type_to_return to get result type
foo(T t)
{
    return typename type_to_return<T>::type(T); // <-- Build a thing!
}
```

I would then specialize the `type_to_return` class for the types I have created. This would make the entry be one function and I could then just define new `type_to_return`s and constructors.

I want `type_to_return<T>::type` to be just `T` if `T` is not some class template. Otherwise I want it to be that class's first template parameter. So for `int`, I get back `int`, and for `MultOp<float,int,double>`, I want to get back `float`.

How do I do that? I think I need to do something like:

```
// Base version
template <typename T>
struct type_to_return
{
    typedef T type;
};

// Specialized type
template <template <typename> class T>
struct type_to_return<T <any_type_somehow> >
{
    typedef template boost::magic_type_unwrapper<T>::param<1>::type type;
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do for `vector<int>`?

Comment: I am not really using vector. I was just making things more simple in my question. I really have a bunch of custom command objects that hold a return type as their first type. I need to be able to pull that type off so the execute functions can know what to return.

Comment: You're not making things simple - you're not specifying what you want. If `T` is `vector<int>` - what do you want the type to be? `int`? What about for `std::array<int, 4>`? Is that not a concern? What about `int` - should that give you `int` or not compile?

Comment: Yeah. I am playing around with expression templates where they keep track of their return type. The first type in the template would always be the desired return type. Think of it like `MultOp<float,int,float>` and `CastOp<float, char>` where the return types would be float. This allows me to pass them in deep and just use `std::common_type()` for the regular operations. I would provide more, but I haven't written much code beyond experimenting with pieces of it to see what is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may implement a `type_unwrapper` as follow:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_unwrapper;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
struct type_unwrapper<C<Ts...>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t type_count = sizeof...(Ts);

    template <std::size_t N>
    using param_t = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
};
```

which works as long there is no template value as in `std::array<T, N>`.

Note also that stl container declare some `typedef` to retrieve there template arguments as `std::vector<T, Alloc>::value_type` which is `T`.

Comment: Wait, I am still a bit confused. How would I use this from `foo()`? Doesn't this require passing something into `Ts` that I don't have?

Comment: Ok, I see. You can just use `type_unwrapper<T>::template param_t<0>`. For some reason I thought you would have to do `type_unwrapper<T, Tparams...>` but it is smart enough to figure that out. Thanks