# How can I retrieve the type a templated object was instantiated with?

Tags: c++, templates, types, template-meta-programming, nested-types

**Problem:**

I would like to get the type a templated type was instantiated with. E. g. for `std::shared_ptr<int>` I want to get `int`. The approach below works for this simple case. I need to instantiate an object of that type, though. This does not work in some cases, e.g. `std::shared_ptr<some_abstract_class>` or if the default constructor is deleted.

Retrieving an abstract type can still be useful if we are able to cast it to a concrete type.

**Question:**

How can I change the code below in a way that there is no need to instantiate any object?

**Follow-up question:**

Is it possible to do this without having to pass an object to this function? Right now I am passing an object of type `outer<inner>` to `get_inner_t`. I would like to avoid this and retrieve `inner` with the help of template metaprogramming only.

**My approach: [Live example.](https://godbolt.org/z/5fTEcx)**

```
template <typename inner, template <typename a> typename outer>
inner get_inner_t(outer<inner> nested_t) {
  (void)nested_t;
  typedef typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<inner>> without_const_cv_innter_t;
  without_const_cv_innter_t i;
  return i;
}
 
int main() {
  auto sp = std::make_shared<int>();
  typedef decltype(get_inner_t(sp)) inner_t;
  inner_t t = 5;
  std::cout << t;
}
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518804/find-template-type-of-a-template-type-c answer your question?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has `element_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just use a template class (struct here) instead of the template function. And retrieve the type of the object with `decltype` and pass it to the template class.

The following is one way to do it:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
struct inner;

template<template<typename>class outter_t, typename inner_t>
struct inner<outter_t<inner_t> >{
    typedef typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<inner_t>::type>::type type;
};
template<typename _t>
using inner_t = typename inner<_t>::type;

int main()
{

      auto sp = std::make_shared<int>();
      typedef inner_t<decltype(sp)> inner_tt;
      inner_tt t = 5;
      std::cout << t;
}
```

This way you don't need to pass the object itself but its type only. I guess this also works for abstract types too.